# Type-I seesaw: order of magnitude of the eigenvalues of effective $M_\nu$

Tags: mass, neutrinos, eigenvalue, approximations, beyond-the-standard-model

Consider a square matrix $C$ constructed out of two other square matrices $A$ and $B$ as $$C=-A^TB^{-1}A.$$ Suppose all the elements of $B$ are very large compared to those of $A$. In such a case, is it guaranteed that all the matrix elements (or all the eigenvalues) of $C$ will also be small?

The preamble above looks like a math question but there is some physics context to it. In the type-I seesaw, the expression for the effective light neutrino mass matrix is given by $$M_\nu=-m_D^TM_R^{-1}m_D$$ where $m_D$ is the Dirac mass and $M_R$ is Majorana mass for the right-handed electroweak singlet $N_R$.

It is often stated that since "the matrix elements of $m_D$ $\ll$ the matrix elements of $M_R$", the eigenvalues of $M_\nu$ (representing light neutrino masses) will also be small? Or is it one of those hand-waving argument by physicists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "one of those hand-waving arguments", aimed at well-meaning, alert consumers. While it plausibly works for most reasonable mass matrices in semi-realistic models, of course you can concoct freak counterexamples that violate your expectation. Here is one.

Take *A* to be an orthogonal rotation, so it does not alter the eigenvalues of 1/*B*. Choose then, for enormous *M* and minuscule *ε*,
$$
B=  \begin{pmatrix}
      M&M-\epsilon\\
      M-\epsilon &M 
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad \Longrightarrow\qquad  B^{-1}=\frac{1}{2\epsilon M-\epsilon^2}  \begin{pmatrix}
      M&\epsilon-M\\
      \epsilon -M&M 
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The (1,1) eigenvector of *B* has eigenvalue ~  2 *M* so a minuscule 1/(2 *M* ) such for the inverse *B<sup>-1</sup>*. However, (1,-1) has a small one, *ε*, for *B*, and thus a *huge one*, 1/ *ε* , for the inverse *B<sup>-1</sup>*.

So *C* could, in principle, have huge eigenvalues.  It is up to your model to avoid such pathologies.